# Failed to build pypiwin32

Tags: python, pywin32

Alright so what I've been trying to do the past hour is install the pywintypes lib and searched up that it was pypiwin32 instead but it doesn't work it fails to build additionally tried installing it manually by downloading the source and running setup.py but got same err: I get this error and I have python 3.10

```
Collecting pypiwin32
  Using cached pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
  Using cached pypiwin32-219.zip (4.8 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Rasmus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Rasmus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3z4zmi2y\\pypiwin32_ec886c51d7334f269d55dee9cd57e04b\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Rasmus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3z4zmi2y\\pypiwin32_ec886c51d7334f269d55dee9cd57e04b\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Rasmus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-6dg0frr7'
         cwd: C:\Users\Rasmus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3z4zmi2y\pypiwin32_ec886c51d7334f269d55dee9cd57e04b\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Rasmus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3z4zmi2y\pypiwin32_ec886c51d7334f269d55dee9cd57e04b\setup.py", line 121
        print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/ca/5c086c18de8f70222787b3e824e755b68d99272531522e77bb381d4f60c8/pypiwin32-219.zip#sha256=06d478295c89dbdd4187e1ac099bb8eab93c29e298bded4e2fbc77009287fa44 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pypiwin32/). Command errored out with exit status 1:
python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only solution I can see is to downgrade from python 3.10 down to [3.9](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-397/)

Comment: Downgraded the python version to 3.9. But it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

`pywin32` version 302 (NOT `pypiwin32`, which looks like a mistake from 2018) was uploaded to PyPi on October 10, 2021, and states in the change log:

> - Support for Python 10, dropped support for Python 3.5 (3.5 security support
>   ended 13 Sep 2020)

Demo (using PyLauncher to update my 3.10 install):

```
C:\>py -3.10 -m pip install pywin32
Collecting pywin32
  Downloading pywin32-302-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (9.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 9.2 MB 6.8 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pywin32
Successfully installed pywin32-302
```

Make sure to run the `Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py` from an administrator command prompt as well to register it properly.  Make sure it runs in the context of the 3.10 installation as well (again using PyLauncher):

```
C:\Python310\Scripts>py -3.10 pywin32_postinstall.py -install
Parsed arguments are: Namespace(install=True, remove=False, wait=None, silent=False, quiet=False, destination='C:\\Python310\\Lib\\site-packages')
Copied pythoncom310.dll to C:\windows\system32\pythoncom310.dll
Copied pywintypes310.dll to C:\windows\system32\pywintypes310.dll
Registered: Python.Interpreter
Registered: Python.Dictionary
Registered: Python
-> Software\Python\PythonCore\3.10\Help[None]=None
-> Software\Python\PythonCore\3.10\Help\Pythonwin Reference[None]='C:\\Python310\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyWin32.chm'
Registered help file
Pythonwin has been registered in context menu
Shortcut for Pythonwin created
Shortcut to documentation created
The pywin32 extensions were successfully installed.
```